# Angular - Use translation from outside 'assets'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngx-translate

I need to add my translation files outside the `assets` directory, something like this:

> src/app/custom/i18n/en.json

I am loading the translations like this:

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './app/custom/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

But this doesn't work as it doesn't find the file:

> GET http://localhost:8100/app/custom/i18n/en.json 404 (Not Found)

I tried to customize the `angular.json` file in order to be able to access files outside 'assets', doing something like this:

```
"assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/app/common",
                "output": "assets"
              }
]
```

but I still get that 404 error. Please advise how could I set the translation to use json files from outside `assets`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify messages file in assests array. As **custom/i18n/en.json** is not specified in an assets array it is not going to be bundled when you build your project. Therefore giving 404 error

```
"assets": [
    {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "src/assets",
        "output": "assets"
    },
    {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "src/app/common",
        "output": "assets"
    },
   "custom/i18n/en.json"
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I actually managed to do it by adding this line: `"src/app/custom"`, because this way I can load multiple .json files (for different languages) from the `custom` directory.